# R: Reading multiline data patterns from file

Tags: regex, r

Here is a file pattern

```
metastring: time1, a,b,c,d,f
144135 42435 345425 2342423
263766 35553 353453 3534553
355345 52454 525252 2423465
245466 45645 355345 6454556
355662 26397 353577 3558676
metastring: time2, a,c,d,f
224234 23423 324234 4242324
312323 13123 312312 1312321
246456 63564 646544 4456456
244424 53556 546456 4645645
```

metastrings consist of time stamp and a,b,c,d are names referring to strings of numbers (e.g. "a" refers to the first number string of the block). Number strings are fixed-width but their quantity is not constant, depends on metastring. 
What I want is either a data.frame structured like this:

```
time1 a 144135 42435 345425 2342423
time1 b 263766 35553 353453 3534553
time1 c 355345 52454 525252 2423465
time1 d 245466 45645 355345 6454556
time1 f 355662 26397 353577 3558676
time2 a 224234 23423 324234 4242324
time2 c 312323 13123 312312 1312321
time2 d 246456 63564 646544 4456456
time2 f 244424 53556 546456 4645645
```

Or to be able to read a single block at a time by matching metastring format and reading lines between two metastrings. Can't find a way to do it, since gsubfn read.pattern seems to read file by a line at a time and I can't get anything further than metastring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a data frame in return, here's a possibility that uses `readLines()` and then does some post-processing on the strings.  In your code, replace `textConnection(text)` with the name of your file.

```
## read the file
dat <- readLines(textConnection(text))
## find the 'metastring' lines
meta <- grepl("metastring", dat, fixed = TRUE)
## split the 'metastring' lines for the first two columns
## then create the first two columns
f2cols <- do.call(
    "rbind", 
    lapply(
        strsplit(dat[meta], "(.*: )|, ?"), 
        function(x) cbind(text1 = x[2], text2 = tail(x, -2))
    )
)
## create the final data frame
cbind(f2cols, read.table(text = dat[!meta]))
#   text1 text2     V1    V2     V3      V4
# 1 time1     a 144135 42435 345425 2342423
# 2 time1     b 263766 35553 353453 3534553
# 3 time1     c 355345 52454 525252 2423465
# 4 time1     d 245466 45645 355345 6454556
# 5 time1     f 355662 26397 353577 3558676
# 6 time2     a 224234 23423 324234 4242324
# 7 time2     c 312323 13123 312312 1312321
# 8 time2     d 246456 63564 646544 4456456
# 9 time2     f 244424 53556 546456 4645645
```

**Data:**

```
text <- "metastring: time1, a,b,c,d,f\n144135 42435 345425 2342423\n263766 35553 353453 3534553\n355345 52454 525252 2423465\n245466 45645 355345 6454556\n355662 26397 353577 3558676\nmetastring: time2, a,c,d,f\n224234 23423 324234 4242324\n312323 13123 312312 1312321\n246456 63564 646544 4456456\n244424 53556 546456 4645645"
```